# write to XML file - howto?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml

I'm working on an iPhone app where I need to use XML files.
I know how to parse XML, Now I need to take info that the user inputs,
and write it into an xml (same one or a new one),
How can I achieve it?

I looked in google and here but part of the guides are not so clear and some are deprecated methods..

Tnx for your help!

Comment: What is exactly not clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an NSMutableString* and append data to it, just in an XML fashion.

```
NSMutableString *xmlstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[xmlstring appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"];
[xmlstring appendString:@"<RegistrationXml xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\n"];
[xmlstring appendString:@"<DataFields>\n"];
[xmlstring appendString:@"<Name>FirstName</Name>\n"];
[xmlstring appendFormat:@"<Value>%@</Value>\n", [self replaceXMLReservedCharactersInString:someString]];
[xmlstring appendString:@"</DataFields>\n"];
[xmlstring appendString:@"</RegistrationXml>\n"];
```

Where

```
- (NSString *)replaceXMLReservedCharactersInString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result;

    result = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];

    return result;
}
```

and then pass it...
if you want to write it to a file, search for NSFileManager.

Comment: @Rob, it's a general example for a general question.
your'e welcome to edit the answer :)

Comment: I got rid of percent-escaping stuff and added the routine to replace reserved characters in the XML value. (I also added `<\DataFields>` to make the example well-formed.) If you don't approve of my edit, feel free to revert and I'll post my own answer.

Comment: BTW, if anyone is interested in why I'm doing the `&`, `<`, and `>` replacements, see [section 2.4 of the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax). If you fail to do this replacement and happen to have these characters (notably `&` or `<`) in your data, you may receive parsing errors when you run the resulting XML through `NSXMLParser`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end,

Write To File:

```
NSMutableString *xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    //Get all data into an NSMutableString
    [xmlString appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"];
    [xmlString appendString:@"<CATALOG>"];
    [xmlString appendString:@"<USER Name=\""];
    [xmlString appendString:username];
    [xmlString appendString:@"\" FBid=\""];
    [xmlString appendString:facebookID];
    [xmlString appendString:@"\" email=\""];
    [xmlString appendString:email];
    [xmlString appendString:@"\"/>\n"];
    [xmlString appendString:@"</CATALOG>\n"];

//Write the NSMutableString into the xml file
NSString *savePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"UserDetails" ofType:@"xml"];
[xmlString writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```